# Directly open removable storage in windows server 2000/2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, removable-media, windows-server-2000

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to run a command line that would open the removable storage portion of the Computer Management tool in Windows Server 2000 and 2003.  I know it is possible to just run compmgmt.msc and then drill down into Storage -> Removable Storage, but I'm working on an application that I wanted to shortcut right to that final layer.

Comment: According to [this site](http://www.diaryfolio.com/msclist/): `ntmsmgr.msc`. If true, please post it as an answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to run Removable Storage directly is `ntmsmgr.msc`.  A list of all the individual msc commands can be found [here](http://www.diaryfolio.com/msclist/).